# URL address hiding in angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, software-design, breadcrumbs

How to hide a browser's URL address bar when clicking on the breadcrumb navigation link in angular??

Able to hide browser URLs when clicking on any links Using "SkipLocationChange" attribute but unable to hide the URL when clicking on the breadcrumb navigation link.

Comment: you want to full screen when click on breadcrumb?